# Upload and resize image in Aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page which allows the user to upload pictures. The problem is that my old users can't resize the image themselves. I want to allow them to upload any size of image and then when the server gets it, it will create a small copy of this picture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are so many approaches to resize images, but i like this one

```
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("FilePath");            
int newwidthimg = 160;                
float AspectRatio = (float)image.Size.Width / (float)image.Size.Height;
int newHeight = Convert.ToInt32(newwidthimg / AspectRatio);
Bitmap thumbnailBitmap = new Bitmap(newwidthimg, newHeight);
Graphics thumbnailGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailBitmap);
thumbnailGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
thumbnailGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
thumbnailGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newwidthimg, newHeight);
thumbnailGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
thumbnailBitmap.Save("FilePath", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
thumbnailGraph.Dispose();
thumbnailBitmap.Dispose();
image.Dispose();
```

I have fix the width because i want all my images having width 160 and height according to the Aspect ratio

Answer (score 9):

You may use some kind of **resizeMethod**.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile pf = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    System.Drawing.Image bm = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(pf.InputStream);
    bm = ResizeBitmap((Bitmap) bm, 100, 100); /// new width, height
    bm.Save(Path.Combine(YOURUPLOADPATH, pf.FileName);
}

private Bitmap ResizeBitmap(Bitmap b, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)result))
        g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);
    return result;
}
```

On the other hand, **uploading** a eg **3 MB file** and **afterwards** **resizing** it to a 20kb pic - does *not* sound *very good* to me. Perhaps you could consider limiting upload file size.

Comment: I like that this option takes the image straight from the HttpPost - and doesn't rely on saving the image to disk first

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a recent solution. Hope it helps

http://forums.asp.net/t/1657138.aspx/1?C+Resize+Profile+Image

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File1.HasFile)
        {
            string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(File1.FileName);
            string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            System.Drawing.Image image_file = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(File1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            int image_height = image_file.Height;
            int image_width = image_file.Width;
            int max_height = 100;
            int max_width = 100;

            image_height = (image_height * max_width) / image_width;
            image_width = max_width;

            if (image_height > max_height)
            {
                image_width = (image_width * max_height) / image_height;
                image_height = max_height;
            }

            Bitmap bitmap_file = new Bitmap(image_file, image_width, image_height);
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            bitmap_file.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            stream.Position = 0;

            byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
            stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

            Profile.Picture = data;
            Profile.PictureType = "image/png";
        }
}
```